# UIGestureRecognizer in UIView Object

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have created a `UIViewController`, which contains a `UIView` object.

I want the `UIView` object response to a single tap by 1 finger, and also pinch by 2 fingers.

I have clicked the **"User Interaction Enabled"** and the **"Multiple touch"** options in the xib.

I create both `UITapGestureRecognizer`, and `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` inside the `UIView` function **initWithFrame:**, as it is the only entry point for the `UIView` object. But the object doesn't response to the `UIGestureRecognizer` objects. Why? Or, where is the best place to put the `UIGestureRecognizer` objects?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        // single tap
        UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];

        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        [self addGestureRecognizer: singleTap];

        // 2 fingers pinch
        UIPinchGestureRecognizer* doubleMove = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleMove:)];

        [self addGestureRecognizer: doubleMove];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Separate issue but you need to `release` the gesture recognizers after the `addGestureRecognizer:` calls.

Comment: Thks. I am using XCode 4.2, and it uses ARC, and the compiler gives me error when I try to release/autorelease any object. I am quite mess up with what I did before with the newest compiler.

Comment: Ok, nevermind.  Not used to "missing" releases yet.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that when you instantiate your custom view subclass in IB, `initWithCoder:` is called. If you had done it programmatically using `initWithFrame:` it would have worked properly.

Two ways you can fix this,

1. Move the gestures setup to a different method and call them in both `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:`. I would recommend doing this if you intend to reuse this component and expose some kind of callbacks on gestures.
2. If you want to implement this once and have a lot of interacting with the controller element, add them in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: UIView does not haev viewDidLoad

Answer (score 3):

I tried your code and it works for me.

Where are you setting the view? Maybe it has any other view in front, or its superview has `userInteractionEnabled` disabled.

I created a UIView subclass and added this code:

```
-(void) handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    NSLog(@"handleSingleTap");
}

-(void) handleDoubleMove:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    NSLog(@"handleDoubleMove");
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        // single tap
        UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];

        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        [self addGestureRecognizer: singleTap];

        // 2 fingers pinch
        UIPinchGestureRecognizer* doubleMove = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleMove:)];

        [self addGestureRecognizer: doubleMove];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then, in my controller:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyView * myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
    [myView release];

}
```

And it works.

Answer (score 1):

i think if you are working with .xib, initialization can also be done in

> -(void)awakeFormNib;

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `GestureRecognizers` is typically done in the `viewDidLoad` method of the `UIViewController`.