# unrecognized selector when loading xib

Tags: ios, ios4, uigesturerecognizer, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS5 Stable App Crashing in iOS4.3 Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019420/ios5-stable-app-crashing-in-ios4-3-simulator)

I have a UIViewController with a xib with a View and a UISwipeGestureRecognizer. When I run in an iOS 6 simulator everything works as intended.

When I run in an iOS 4.3 simulator and attempt to access the viewController.view which causes the xib to be loaded for the first time, then I get this error message:

```
-[UISwipeGestureRecognizer initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7385340
```

Switch back to iOS6, loads no problem. iOS 4.3, crash.

This is my IBOutlet definition for the gesture recognizer I'm creating in that xib:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizerSwipeClosed;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was already answered: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019420/ios5-stable-app-crashing-in-ios4-3-simulator).
I don't know the exact version when UIGestureRecognizers were added to Interface Builder. But it seems that it is not supported in iOS 4.3.
Any object loaded from a nib is initialized with `initWithCoder:`. So in iOS 4.3 there is no such method to initialize the gesture.
What you can do though is create the gestures programmatically, this will work in iOS 4.3.

Comment: /facepalm Thanks! I had checked to make sure the code was available in 4.3, I never thought this might be an issue.